# Fetch XML to get All Records that do not have any Associated Records of a Particular Entity

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

This Advanced Find Fetch XML retrieves all Cases that have associated Service Activities:

```xml
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="true">
    <entity name="incident">
        <attribute name="title" />
        <attribute name="ticketnumber" />
        <attribute name="createdon" />
        <attribute name="incidentid" />
        <order attribute="title" descending="false" />
        <link-entity name="serviceappointment" from="wl_serviceactivitiesid" to="incidentid" alias="aa">
        </link-entity>
</entity>
```

What would be the Fetch XML or View logic to show all Cases that **do not** have associated Service Activities.
Can there be a *not* before the :

```
<link-entity>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking this may work:

Basically it does an outer join to the serviceappointment, then excludes any items that have a primary key.

```xml
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="true">
    <entity name="incident">
        <attribute name="title" />
        <attribute name="ticketnumber" />
        <attribute name="createdon" />
        <attribute name="incidentid" />
        <order attribute="title" descending="false" />
        <link-entity name="serviceappointment" from="wl_serviceactivitiesid" to="incidentid" alias="aa" link-type="outer">
            <filter type="and">
                <condition attribute="wl_serviceactivitiesid" operator="null" />
            </filter>
        </link-entity>
</entity>
```